# ALTER TABLE ... ROW_FORMAT=Compressed times out

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to change a table with the command:

```
ALTER TABLE ... ROW_FORMAT=Compressed
```

This fails after 15 minutes, the log says:

```
InnoDB: Error: semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds
InnoDB: We intentionally crash the server, because it appears to be hung.
```

and I'm left with a large temporary table:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 37G Jun  1 10:53 #sql-ib788-3264739711.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 15K Jun  1 10:37 #sql-13e5_95.frm
```

Whereas the table is only 100MB. I'm using MariaDB 10.0.16 on SLES 12.

I've actually backed up this table and restored it on a test VM running openSUSE 13.2/MariaDB 10.0.13 and the ALTER TABLE takes 60 seconds. Unfortunately I need to perform this process on the actual server.

The table has approximately 100,000 rows. If I cut it down to 1,000ish rows the statement works (the exact number of rows depends on whether I remove from the start or end of the table).

The log reports the InnoDB status and I noticed this:

```
---TRANSACTION 8665481870, not started
MySQL thread id 4, OS thread handle 0x7f8bf01b3700, query id 709 localhost user1 altering table
ALTER TABLE mdl_user ROW_FORMAT=Compressed
---TRANSACTION 8665481869, ACTIVE 253 sec
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
MySQL thread id 4, OS thread handle 0x7f8bf01b3700, query id 709 localhost user1 altering table
ALTER TABLE mdl_user ROW_FORMAT=Compressed
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 8665481871, sees < 8665481870
```

Which looks to me like it's trying to use two threads which are deadlocked although I may be misunderstanding what this is telling me.

What's going wrong?

Comment: You could try [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) - that will create new table, clone all data and then swap the tables - but if it is metadata lock, then the swap won't be succesful too probably..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this on my test VM (where the ALTER TABLE works) with --dry-run. I get "Dry run complete" followed by several minutes max CPU followed by "Killed" (I didn't press Ctrl+C). I'd like to avoid troubleshooting a presumably separate issue...

Comment: I've downloaded SLES 12 on evaluation, created a VM, installed the same MariaDB version (mariadb-10.0.16-15.1), copied the table across, ran the ALTER TABLE statement and the same problem occurs. So, looking like a MariaDB bug either upstream or packaged version.

Comment: I suggest using 10.0.19 to test it and maybe report it - if you could make it into some compact test case then that would be best - I did not find specific bugreport with similar symptoms..

Answer (score 2):

Please note that I am not a MySQL developer, I use MS SQL Server.  But the behavior in your post suggests the following:

It does not look like a deadlock to me, especially with the error messages:

```
InnoDB: Error: semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds
InnoDB: We intentionally crash the server, because it appears to be hung.
```

A deadlock normally would quickly determine which connection to roll back instead of processing up to 600 seconds before crashing the server.

Likely what is happening is that the table metadata change (the ALTER TABLE) *cannot happen* while there are other transactions using the table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/metadata-locking.html

The link says, in part: "To ensure transaction serializability, the server must not permit one session to perform a data definition language (DDL) statement on a table that is used in an uncompleted explicitly or implicitly started transaction in another session."

EDIT: Sorry for the misunderstanding regarding deadlocks.

Per this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860111/warning-a-long-semaphore-wait

Ensure that: `Innodb_adaptive_hash_index=0`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sure that there are no other transactions running. Indeed, surely they would be listed by the InnoDB Monitor whereas the two in my post are the only two listed. Also presumably this wouldn't explain why the ALTER works if I delete a large chunk of the rows.

Comment: Just to show there are no other transactions running `SHOW PROCESSLIST` reports:
*************************** 1. row ***************************`
      Id: 2
    User: user1
    Host: localhost
      db: moodle_test
 Command: Query
    Time: 195
   State: altering table
    Info: ALTER TABLE mdl_user ROW_FORMAT=Compressed
Progress: 0.000
*************************** 2. row ***************************
      Id: 4
    User: user1
    Host: localhost
      db: moodle_test
 Command: Query
    Time: 0
   State: init
    Info: SHOW PROCESSLIST
Progress: 0.000

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Added one solution in edit.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The setting innodb_adaptive_hash_index was on, I've set it to 0 and restarted the service (and done SHOW VARIABLES to confirm change), unfortunately same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a customer system and they have the SUSE account and are unwilling to log the issue, I ended up downgrading the MariaDB package to resolve this. I did:

```
# zypper remove mariadb mariadb-errormessages mariadb-client
# zypper install mariadb-10.0.11-6.4
```